# Faster code to make a DataFrame from existing DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe, append

I have the following pandas DataFrame from which I want to create a new DataFrame.

```
   Id UserId  BadgeName            Date              Class  TagBased
0   2   23  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
1   3   22  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
2   4   21  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
3   5   20  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
4   6   19  Autobiographer  2016-01-12T18:44:49.267     3   False
```

Here class:3=bronze,2=silver,1=gold. I want to create a subset only for those users for whom TagBased=True. Note: Here TagBased is Object and not Bool. The DataFrame should also contain the following information:

- No. of Gold, Silver and Bronze
- Total No. of TagBased Badges
- Total No. of Badges

The final DataFrame should look like this:

```
UserId  Gold  Silver  Bronze  TagBased  TotalBadges
854      5     2       0        3           7
897      0     4       0        1           4
.....
```

I have tried the following code(Given I evaluated the usersId with TagBased=True separately) but I feel there can be a more efficient way to deal with it.

```
columns = ['UserId','Gold','Silver','Bronze','Tag Based','Total Badges']
df_tagBased = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
    
Gold = 0
Silver = 0
Bronze = 0
TagBased = 0
TotalBadges = 0
data=[]

for i in tagBased_counts.keys():
  for index, row in df_Badge.iterrows():
    if row['UserId'] == i: 
        if(row['Class']=='1'):  
            Gold +=1
        elif(row['Class']=='2'): 
           Silver +=1
        elif(row['Class']=='3'): 
           Bronze +=1
  TotalBadges = Gold + Silver + Bronze
  TagBased = tagBased_counts.get(i)
  data.append({'UserId':i,'Gold':Gold,'Silver':Silver,'Bronze':Bronze,'Tag Based':TagBased,'Total Badges':TotalBadges})
  
df_tagBased = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop! Here is your data with a couple extra lines.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BadgeName': ['Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer',
  'Autobiographer'],
 'Class': ['Bronze', 'Bronze', 'Bronze', 'Bronze', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
 'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000'),
  pd.Timestamp('2016-01-12 18:44:49.267000')],
 'Id': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 'TagBased': ['False', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'True'],
 'UserId': [23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 23, 22]})
```

Added these to illustrate with gold and silver badges as well. Then converted to the data types you specified.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['TagBased'] = df['TagBased'].astype(str)
df['Class'] = df['Class'].astype(str).replace({'3': 'Bronze', '2': 'Silver', '1': 'Gold'})
```

And finally performed some groupby's and concatenations to obtain the desired result:

```
gold_silver_bronze = df.groupby(['UserId'])['Class'].value_counts().unstack()
tag_based = df[df['TagBased'] == 'True'].groupby(['UserId'])['TagBased'].count()
total = df.groupby(['UserId'])['Id'].nunique()
total.name = 'TotalBadges'

desired = pd.concat([gold_silver_bronze, tag_based, total], axis=1).fillna(0)

desired
```